# Error in Google Cloud when installing sentence transformers and torch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google-compute-engine

Using Google Cloud SSH command line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge sentence-transformers
```

Results in the following messages:

```
unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json retrying with next repodata source
collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \Killed
```

see:
[image]

the message collecting package metadata took a long time and then printed \Killed. Could you please help with this? How can I install sentence-transformers?

**[Edit] PS.** I have successfully installed a number of packages, and in addition to above, installing pytorch fails. Previously I was using E2 instance with 1-128 GB memory, and I created a new N2 instance with 2-864 GB memory, this time did not install conda and instead followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup#linux) to install python. The problem still continues and I get the message "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device"

Comment: Check `sudo dmesg` if it was killed by the oom killer. If yes you need more RAM.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks, yes, once the process was running for a long time it had run out of memory. I had installed other packages successfully prior to sentencetransformer. I deleted the virtual env, created new and first run conda install numpy and then conda install -c conda-forge sentence-transformers. Still the same issue.

Comment: Well, what do you expect if you don't increase the RAM?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please see I have edited my question. I created a new instance with more memory and I still am not able to install some packages like sentence-transformers or torch.