# How to install ctransformers with Conda

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google-compute-engine

I am looking for the standard conda command that allows me to install [ctransformers](https://pypi.org/project/ctransformers/). I have found the following, but I am not sure if they are equivalent to pip install ctransformers:

https://anaconda.org/jcmorin-ana-org/ctransformers

https://anaconda.org/jcmorin-ana-org/ctransformers-gpu

https://anaconda.org/jcmorin-ana-org/ctransformers-cpu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Google Cloud when installing sentence transformers](https://serverfault.com/questions/1147991/error-in-google-cloud-when-installing-sentence-transformers)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. Instead, edit your question to include more information.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, these are two different questions. Installing sentence transformers has a conda command, but it fails for some reason. Installing Ctransformers on the other hand, does not seem to have a conda command, and I am looking for one. Two seperate questions!